# MATLAB and Arudino, set registers (PWM)

Tags: matlab, arduino, pwm, servo

I am using an Arduino MEGA with MATLAB for the first time to try and control a servo motor, the issue is that the default PWM frequency for the pin I am trying to use is at 976Hz, while I need it to be around 50Hz. I found code for changing the timer 0 B register that affects this frequency but only for use in the Arudino IDE.

So basically, I need to send the following command to the Arduino:

```
TCCR0B = TCCR0B & B11111000 | B00000101;
```

Does anyone know how to do this while using the Arduino MEGA through MATLAB? Is there not a way to have straight up Arudino code in the .m file through some function/syntax? Or is there another way to manipulate the TCCR0B register via MATLAB? I know I could do this on the Arduino IDE but I really need to use MATLAB for the rest of this project.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are you using? embedded coder?

Comment: No? I am using MATLAB R2015a, an Arduino Mega2560 and the MATLAB & Simulink Arduino support libraries.

Comment: Gave a look at the lib and it seems to me that you're out of luck. Easiest workaround is communicating via your "own protocol" over serial port (you'll have a one step delay vs equivalent simulation and simulink will "stuck" waiting for stream input on COM reads ).

Comment: Ah, well thanks for taking the time to look at it. I might try that but I am also going to look into alternatives.